# File not found exception using unfreez_wrapper.dll

Tags: c#, winforms

Could not load file or assembly 'unfreez_wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

```
ei = new ExtractImages(StartTags,LastTags,Maps, localFilename, UrlsPath);
```

ei is a new class that use the file: unfreez_wrapper.dll
I added the file the dll file twice tried now from different locations on my hard disk.

The full exception message:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024770
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'unfreez_wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
  Source=WeatherMaps
  FileName=unfreez_wrapper.dll
  FusionLog=""
  StackTrace:
       at WeatherMaps.ExtractImages..ctor(List`1 FirstTags, List`1 LastTags, List`1 Maps, String LocalFileDir, String UrlsDir)
       at WeatherMaps.Form1..ctor() in d:\C-Sharp\WeatherMaps\WeatherMaps\WeatherMaps\Form1.cs:line 60
       at WeatherMaps.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\WeatherMaps\WeatherMaps\WeatherMaps\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

The file properties:

```
Aliases: Global
Copy Local: True
Embed Interop: False
```

The rest I can't change.
When I put the mouse on the file properties on the Path I see the path where the file is original. But for some reason it's not copying the file to the current project Debug directory.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: When i'm doing in the new class or in Form1: using unfreez_wrapper; i'm not getting any errors only when i run the program i'm getting the message that it cant find the file.

Comment: Not sure, have reference the dll using its namespace?  for example: `using unfreez_wrapper`

Comment: Is the Target framework of your project (in Project properties) set to .Net Framework Client Profile? If so changing it to .Net framework 4 could work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the VS has some problems with copying the file to the output directory. Maybe you don't have enough privileges? Consult the build output window to see, if you didn't get any errors.

However, you can always copy the required .dll yourself manually. That should be the fastest way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Is the assembly in the `GAC` or any place the might be overriding the assembly that you think is being loaded? This is usually the result of an `incorrect assembly being loaded`,

||

If you have one project referencing another project (such as a 'Windows Application' type referencing a 'Class Library') and both have the same Assembly name, you'll get this error. You can either strongly name the referenced project or (even better) rename the assembly of the referencing project (under the 'Application' tab of project properties in VS).